# Eclipse IDE with Java Content Assist Overriding Field Names

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

I'm completely new to Java and learning it coming from a C# background.

I have Eclipse installed as my IDE of choice currently; and I've tried to set up the 'Content Assist' so that it works like Intellisense in Visual Studio; i.e it pops up as soon as I start typing anything.

However, I've noticed that it irritatingly appends things on the end of my field names when I press the semicolon key. For example, if I type:

private String firstName

Then when I add the semicolon (provided I'm fast enough), I get this:

private String firstNameString;

Is there some way to turn that off? I couldn't see any way in the preferences.

Comment: Check your eclipse's key bindings. I suppose you set it to complete a word automatically when a semicolon is matched.

Comment: The only key binding under Word Completion is Alt+/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after about a year of Java: Use [IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Answer (score 1):

I spoke to someone in the Eclipse IRC channel and was told that this functionality can't be disabled. In fact, for people like me who are used to C# and VS's Intellisense, there is no real solution.

The only two options are:

1: To revert to the standard option of having the Content Assist list pop up only when you press '.' (though it can be opened manually with Ctrl+Space at any time, I don't like having to do this extra combo every time, especially for a learner)

2: Keep it like intellisense but  put up with Eclipse autocompleting field names whenever I enter a semicolon.

To be honest, neither option seems satisfactory, so I'd suggest trying other IDEs for Visual Studio fans looking to migrate, like me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to set up the Content Assist Eclipse feature to work like the VS intellisense, but, in Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced, there are 2 list, if you uncheck "Java Proposals" in both of them and check "Java Type Proposals", you should fix the type name suffix auto insertion problem.

[image]

Also, you could try [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/), it is a based java IDE with good Autocompletion capabilities (it also could show documentation alongside autocompletion and insert code templates as Visual Assist does)

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I tried what you said and it is marginally better but the assist seems to think that whenever I press an 'operator' key (such as .,(); =+-/) that I want to accept the first highlighted option in the list, which is the problem. In Visual Studio only ENTER or TAB will accept an option in the list; and if I could make eclipse do that it would be great, but there's apparently no option. Nonetheless, thanks for your help.